# Can my married spouse join me with her student visa in Germany?

Tags: germany

I’m a third world country citizen who has a settlement residence permit in Germany. I am married to a spouse from my home country and she has never been to Germany.

I’m working now and my take home salary is enough to cover for two people. However, next year my partner will study in Germany in a different state (*Bundesland*) than mine and she will get a visa for the purposes of studying to enter Germany.

I have a few questions, please share your knowledge:

1. Can she live in a different German state from where I'm living because she will study there? Occasionally, we would visit each other but we won’t live together because of our different occupations.
2. Can we register our marriage at *Bürgeramt* with the civil marriage certificate provided in my home country? Does she need to be physically with me in the office for registering?
3. Is she allowed to work more than the limited hours for a student, because she is the spouse of a settlement residency?
4. I have a job and pay monthly AOK health insurance contributions. Can she join me as well as a family member as she only has a marginal part‑time job (*geringfügige Beschäftigung* a. k. a. *Minijob*) which is remunerated less than 520 euros / month?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your country?  The answer to question (2) would depend on the country, and I am only familiar with several of the third world country rules.